# How to call github webservice in java program

Tags: java, web-services, github

I want to create a java web application that fetches data from github using github webservices. How do i call the service and how do i fetch the data from github.

Comment: https://developer.github.com/v3 and https://developer.github.com/v4

Answer (score 0):

I'll start by assuming that by "fetch data from github" you mean that you're going to use an external JAR that someone has created and placed on Github. These APIs are incredibly useful as a tool.

When managing external APIs, the best resource is Apache Maven. If you're using Eclipse, you can create a Maven Project and work from there.

[Maven Documentation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/)

Maven allows people to access APIs directly and not having to put jars locally which frees up memory space. Maven itself is rather simple to use initially, but requires basic knowledge of XML. There are lots of tutorials on Youtube probably, and there's always Stack Overflow for more help. :)